# Is there a way to print out an object from a script as it would appear in the REPL? (e.g. myList: List[String] = List(Hello there, World!)

Tags: scala

I'm coming from a long time Python background. I've always leaned heavily on the `type` function in Python to spit out what kind of object I'm working with.

e.g.

```
In[0]:    print type("Hello")
Out[0]:   >>> string

In[0]:    print type(1234)
Out[0]:   >>> int
```

As I make my way into `Scala` territory, there are times when I'm not entirely sure what kind of object I've ended up with. being able to lay down a quick `print type(obj)` whenever I get a little lost would be a huge help.

e.g.

```
println(type(myObj))  /* Whatever the scala equivalent would be */
>>> myObj: List[String] = List(Hello there, World!)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scala equivalent of this would be the getClass method (from Java) on java.lang.Object.

For instance:

```
scala> 1.getClass
res0: Class[Int] = int

scala> Nil.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type] = class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$

scala> "hello".getClass
res2: Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access high-fidelity type information using reflection as of Scala 2.10.

Make sure to add the scala-reflect JAR to your classpath beforehand.

A little helper method is useful here:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def showTypeOf[T: TypeTag](obj: T) {
  println(typeOf[T])
}
```

Usage:

```
showTypeOf(List(1, 2, 3)) // prints List[Int]
```